# Randomly spawn an object when enemies die Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, game-development, phaser-framework

I would like to randomly spawn a sprite when an enemy dies.
Example: There is a 1 in 5 chance that when an enemy dies, it drops an object (sprites that increase your HP).

Any idea how this can be done?
I did some research, but I didn't find much.

Comment: Are you asking about the randomness part or about how to spawn a sprite?

Comment: about the randomness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *randomness* in a Phaser application, I would use the Phaser's Math helper function `Between` ([here is the link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Math.html#.Between__anchor)).
It creates a random number *(whole number)* from the first number to the last one *(including the last number, perfect for dice)*.

So for *1 in 5*, you just need to select one number from the interval like `5`and compare it with a call to the `Between` function. And only if it matches, you drop/create the sprite.

**Just like this:**

```
if(Phaser.Math.Between(1, 5) === 5){
    // .. drop "loot" / health-object
}
```

**Here a small Demo:**
*(In this demo something could be dropped or not, depending on your luck. 20% is pretty low)*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        create
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function create () {
  
    this.add.text(10, 10, 'Click to red Boxes')
    let graphics = this.make.graphics({x: 0, y: 0, add: false});
    graphics.fillStyle(0xFF0000);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
    graphics.generateTexture('enemy', 20, 20)
    
    let enemiesGroup = this.add.group({
        defaultKey: 'enemy',
        maxSize: 10
    });
    
    let maxEnemiesToShow = 10
    for(let idx = 0; idx < maxEnemiesToShow; idx++){
      // here the function is used to spawn enemies randomly on screen
      const x = Phaser.Math.Between(20, config.width - 20);
      const y = Phaser.Math.Between(40, config.height /2 );

      let enemy = enemiesGroup.get(x, y);
      
      enemy.setInteractive()
        .on('pointerdown', () => {
            // 1 in 5 
            if(Phaser.Math.Between(1, 5) === 5){
                // Drop object
                this.add.rectangle(enemy.x, enemy.y, 10, 10, 0xFFFF00);
            }
          enemy.destroy();
        })

    }
   
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

**Bonus *(because I find this Phaser function especially useful)*:**

If you want to select different *loot*/outcome in phaser you, could even let phaser select from a selected `Array`, with the function `Phaser.Math.RNG.pick(...)` ([link to documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Math.RandomDataGenerator.html#pick__anchor))

**Bonus Demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        create
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function create () {
  
    this.add.text(10, 10, 'Click to red Boxes')
    let graphics = this.make.graphics({x: 0, y: 0, add: false});
    graphics.fillStyle(0xFF0000);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
    graphics.generateTexture('enemy', 20, 20)

    let enemiesGroup = this.add.group({
        defaultKey: 'enemy',
        maxSize: 10
    });
    
    let maxEnemiesToShow = 10
    for(let idx = 0; idx < maxEnemiesToShow; idx++){
      const x = Phaser.Math.Between(20, config.width - 20);
      const y = Phaser.Math.Between(40, config.height /2 );

      let enemy = enemiesGroup.get(x, y);
      
      let loot = [0x00ff00, 0xffff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0, 0x0];
      
      enemy
        .setInteractive()
        .on('pointerdown', () => {
          // Select Colro from an Array of possibilities
          let color = Phaser.Math.RND.pick(loot);
          // only drop item if color is not black
          if(color > 0){
              this.add.rectangle(enemy.x, enemy.y, 10, 10, color);  
          }
          enemy.destroy();
        })
    }
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

> Phaser Random functions, have the added bonus that you can create your own `RandomDataGenerator` with a specific `seed` if you want, that the random numbers, that are created, are generated in the same sequence. Great for testing and so.

Comment: but he said he wants "There is a 1 in 5 chance", meaning on every 5 enemies one of them should give you loot but your answer doesn't insure that, or am I understanding this the wrong way?

Comment: @ChamsddineBouzaine I think you are missunderstanding this. I assumed that with 1 in 5 it is that, there is a  20% chance, that a enemy drops loot. If one would want to change this to ensure, that atleast every fifth enemy drops loot, one would just need a *"global"* counter, that is incremented on each kill,set to zero on each loot drop and also check `if(counter > 0 && counter % 5 == 0 )` and if so drop loot. But this is not really 1 in 5, it only improves the odds for the player. I hope my explaination makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

For a 1/5 chance, you can use JavaScript's `Math.random`.

`Math.random()` will return a float between 0 and 1.

To not hard code this, you can use a function like the following which will return true or false given an odds (in your case `1/5`)

```js
function rollRandom(odds) {
  return Math.random() < odds;
}

console.log(rollRandom(1/5))
```